# Why is my Nancy call to Bind<T>() returning an empty object?

Tags: c#, json, rest, nancy

I am having trouble getting the `Bind<T>()` method to work with a POST request in Nancy.  I have this class *:

```
public class MyPost
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
}
```

And I have this NancyModule that simply mirrors the POST data:

```
public class ConfigModule : NancyModule
{
    public ConfigModule() : base("/config")
    {
        Post["/update"] = parameters =>
        {
            var mypost = this.Bind<MyPost>();
            return Response.AsJson<MyPost>(mypost);
        };
    }
}
```

When I send this POST request using the Chrome extension Postman:

```
POST /config/update HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9664
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ "title": "my title 33", "content": "my content" }
```

I get this response:

```
{
    "title": null,
    "content": null
}
```

When I debug my post method, I see that all of the properties of the mypost object are null.  Why is this?  When I call this.Request.Body.AsString(), I get the POST data that I expect.

* *I made the property names lowercase because when I converted a MyPost object to JSON using Response.AsJson(arg), the keys were lowercase.*

Comment: I'm not familiar with Nancy, but what happens if you set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` on your request?

Comment: I have to figure out how to do that.  There must be some content-type setting in Postman

Comment: @ChrisHayes that was it thanks.  This page helped me http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/player-management/guides/postman.html

Comment: @user2023861 - just go to the headers tab, add a new header for `Content-Type` with the value `application/json` as Chris said.

Comment: I am having the same problem although the Content-Type is correct. Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Don't forget to define a setter, like I did! You won't get an error thrown. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `Content-Type` to `application/json` by the **orange** `JSON (application/json)` below

[image: application/json]